# Laravel: Edit Data on Same Page it's Displayed on

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, crud

I'd like to make changes to user data on the same page it's been displayed. 
Basically, I want to either select verified or rejected, click submit button and the page refreshes with the change. 
So i have this code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Receipt</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <form method='POST' action="{{ action('PaymentController@update' , $user->id )}}"
                  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <th scope="row">{{$user->id}}</th>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/{{$user->receipt}}">{{$user->receipt}}</a>
                </td>
                @if( $user->payment_status != NULL )
                    <td>
                        PAYMENT VERIFIED
                    </td>
                @else
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select multiple class="form-control-sm" id="exampleFormControlSelect2" name="nsap_reg"
                                    required="">
                                <option value="verified">Verified</option>
                                <option value="NULL">Rejected</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                @endif
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'nsap_reg' => 'required',
    ]);

    $payment_status = \App\User::find($id);

    ['nsap_reg' => $request->nsap_reg];

    $payment_status->save();
    return redirect('user-status');
}
```

My problem is nothing happens when I click submit, the page just refreshes.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you created select list with multiple select and when you are saving data to database then you sending array data to saving.
But you have to firstly convert that to json and then set to save.

**Below is the example to save multi-select `nsap_reg`.**

```
<?php

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'nsap_reg.*' => 'required',
    ]);

    $payment_status = \App\User::find($id);

    $payment_status->nsap_reg = json_encode($request->input('nsap_reg'));

    $payment_status->save();
    return redirect('user-status');
}
```

**But if you are using single select then remove `multiple` attribute from the select list and then use this code**

```
<?php

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'nsap_reg' => 'required',
    ]);

    $payment_status = \App\User::find($id);

    $payment_status->nsap_reg = $request->input('nsap_reg');

    $payment_status->save();
    return redirect('user-status');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the value of `nsap_reg` to user object and save it.

`$payment_status = \App\User::find($id);
$payment_status->nsap_reg = $request->nsap_reg;
$payment_status->save();`